# Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column; Data with same column names

Tags: r, error-handling, merge

I am trying to merge two files by the County Code variable using this code: data <- merge(covid, overdose, by ="County Code"). However, I keep receiving this error: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column. The column name is the same in both datasets. I am unsure of what the problem is.

Comment: They both return all the variables in each dataset.

Comment: For dataset one here are the first 5: [1] "ï..ID"                        "County.Name"                  "Date"                        
 [4] "New.Cases"                    "X7.day.Average.New.Cases"  
For dataset 2 here are the first 5:  [1] "ï..ID"                                  "Incident.ID"                           
 [3] "Incident.Date"                          "Incident.Time"                         
 [5] "Day"

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).